# How to achieve adding items via appsync using awscurl (Problem with escape)

Tags: curl, aws-appsync

I am currently trying to add items via appsync using awscurl.

For your reference, the command is as follows.

```
  awscurl -X POST \
    --service appsync \
    --region ap-northeast-1 \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "query":"mutation MyMutation($input: CreateTaskInput!) { createTask(input: $input) { jobIdOrder } }", "variables": { "input": { "jobIdOrder": "'${ jobIdOrder}'", "version": "'${version}'", "product": "'${product}'", "batch": "'${batch}'", "batchName": "' ${batchName}'", "versionProductBatch": "'${versionProductBatch}'","jobId": "'${jobId}'", "order": "'${order}'", "title": "'${title}'", "args": "'${args}'" } } }' \
```

And the content of one args is, for example, below.

```
[ { "option": "null", "order": 1, "value": "7194-test-1" }, { "option": "-i", "order": 2, "value": " /7194/big-input.txt" }, { "option": "-o", "order": 3, "value": "/7194/big-output.txt" } ]
```

The problem is that there is a double quotation (") in the contents of args so the following error occurs.

```
awscurl: error: unrecognized arguments: "option": "null", "order": 1, "value": "7194-test-1" }, { "option": "-i", "order": 2, "value": "/7194/big-input.txt" }, { "option": "-o", "order": 3, "value": "/7194/big-output.txt" } ]"} } } https://gbcaerkt4nbyvb4k577cisisse.appsync-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/graphql
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to write query so that appsycn can be executed successfully.

I apologize for the inconvenience, thank you for your kind support.

What I have tried

Works

- Writing directly in the args

```
  awscurl -X POST \
    --service appsync \
    --region ap-northeast-1 \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "query":"mutation MyMutation($input: CreateTaskInput!) { createTask(input: $input) { jobIdOrder } }", "variables": { "input": { "jobIdOrder": "'${ jobIdOrder}'", "version": "'${version}'", "product": "'${product}'", "batch": "'${batch}'", "batchName": "' ${batchName}'", "versionProductBatch": "'${versionProductBatch}'","jobId": "'${jobId}'", "order": "'${order}'", "title": "'${title}'", "args": [ { "option": "null", "order": 1, "value": "7194-test-1" }, { "option": "-i ", "order": 2, "value": "/7194/big-input.txt" }, { "option": "-o", "order": 3, "value": "/7194/big- output.txt" } ] } } }' \
```

Does not work

- Escape " with bachslash

```
args1=${args//\"/\\\"}
#args1 becomes like this →"[ { \"option\": \"null\", \"order\": 1, \"value\": \"7194-test-1\" }, { \"option\": \"-i\", \"order\": 2, \"value\": \"/7194/big-input.txt\" }, { \"option\": \"-o\", \"order\": 3, \"value\": \"/7194/big-output.txt\" } ]"
```

```
  awscurl -X POST \
    --service appsync \
    --region ap-northeast-1 \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "query":"mutation MyMutation($input: CreateTaskInput!) { createTask(input: $input) { jobIdOrder } }", "variables": { "input": { "jobIdOrder": "'${jobIdOrder}'",  "version": "'${version}'",  "product": "'${product}'", "batch": "'${batch}'", "batchName":  "'"${batchName}"'", "versionProductBatch":  "'${versionProductBatch}'", "jobId":  "'${jobId}'",  "order": "'${order}'", "title": "'"${title}"'", "args": "'${args1}'"} } }' \
    $ENDPOINT_URL
```

- Change the quotation to only single ("args": '${args1}')
- Add the double quotation ("args": "'"${args1}"'")
- Using --data-binary, instead of -d
  etc..